# Multiselect picker

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Been looking for a multiselect picker of some sort in Appcelerator and as I understand it's not available out of the box. What I want to do is being able to select multiple rows in a single column.

What would be the recommended strategy to getting a multiselect to work in Appcelerator?

Or even better, does anyone know of any CommonJS module with a neat solution?